# Achieve button click in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, ipad, delegates, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Is there a way I can get the button click event from a button inside a `UICollectionViewCell`? I used a nib to populate the collection view, the cell has the button but its action is not getting called.  I think the problem is with the delegate being called. How can I fix this?

How I created :

1. Added an empty nib, created a collection view cell
2. Added a .h and .m file and made the cell nib's files owner as the class created
3. Wrote an action in the class.
4. Connected the button to the action

Is there a way I can get the action?
What  am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have the function in FileOwner? Please try removing the link to action and reconnect it.

Comment: Close request? Why? Oh ok Edited

Comment: File owner is the nib's class itself?

Comment: Yeah it is.That is also why i can connect the outlet right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the button action like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellId" forIndexPath:[indexPath row]]; 

    [[cell myButton] addTarget:self action:@selector(myClickEvent:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;

}


- (IBAction)myClickEvent:(id)sender event:(id)event {

    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:_myCollectionArray];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_myCollectionArray indexPathForItemAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];

}
```

Answer (score 20):

It is important that you create the cell in the Nib by dragging a "Collection View Cell" from the Objects panel. If you use an UIView and just change the class for this cell in the Identity Inspector then the action will not work.

Comment: This was my exact issue. Glad I found this suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Here is swift 3.1 code

```
// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! BlueCircleViewCell

    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
    cell.bgImage.image = UIImage(named: items[indexPath.row])
    cell.addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addCircle(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

//        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan // make cell more visible in our example project

    return cell
}

func addCircle(_ sender:UIButton){
    //CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    let buttonPosition:CGPoint = sender.convert(.zero, to: self.collectionView)
    let indexPath:IndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: buttonPosition)!
    onAddBlueCircle(indexPath: indexPath)
}
```